# ubuntu 16.04 slurm srun failed with intel mpi?

Tags: 16.04, intel, mpi

I am trying to install slurm in a cluster running ubuntu 16.04.

I am using intel mpi and the installation directory is located at the head node /opt/intel/impi_5.01.

According to the slurm instruction, it needs to export the libpmi.so variable. https://slurm.schedmd.com/mpi_guide.html#intel_mpi

But, I installed slurm-llnl via ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get slurm-llnl
```

and I am not sure where the libpmi.so is located? So, I did a search and found a file here, is this the file I'm looking for?

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpmi.so
```

Anyway, I export the variable and I tried

```
srun -p old -N3 -n24 hostname
```

It returns,

```
rolly@head:~$ srun -p old -N3 -n24 hostname
node02
node02
node02
node02
node02
node02
node02
node02
node01
node01
head
head
node01
head
head
head
node01
node01
head
node01
head
head
node01
node01
```

It appears working.

But as I run my task,

```
srun -p old -N3 -n24 ~/QE530-CPU/espresso-5.3.0/bin/pw.x
```

It produced errors,

```
mpiexec_node02: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node02: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node01: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node01: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node02: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node02: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node02: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node02: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node02: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node01: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node01: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node02: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node01: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node01: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node01: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
mpiexec_node01: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_rolly); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
```

I believe the error prompts are due to running mpiexec with intel-mpi, it should be using mpirun instead.

How can I correct the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that by exporting the environmental variable, export I_MPI_PMI_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpmi.so, kills the mpirun. if this is set, mpirun -n 24 -ppn 8 -f ~/machines.LINUX ~/QE530-CPU/espresso-5.3.0/bin/pw.x fails. If it is removed, mpirun works again. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.

1) `sudo apt-get install mpich`

2) `srun --mpi=pmi2`

3) mkl and intel related environmental variables are loaded correctly.

I hope this is going to help someone having similar problem.